# Can I do "using namespace.class"?

Tags: c#, class, dll, reference, namespaces

I was wondering this as I apparently cannot do this. I have added my .dll as as reference and have added  `using myNamespace;`
but whenever I want to call one of the functions, I have to use
`myClass.myMethod();`
is there anything I can do so I wont need to reference the class name when calling a procedure? So I would only need
`myMethod();`

Comment: If the method you're calling is static, then you will call it via the class name

Comment: Yes, the methods are static, is there any way to avoid having to do `myClass.myMethod();` instead of `myMethod();`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't for now. But in `C# 6.0` you will be able able to use using directives for `static` classes.

For example:

```
using System.Console;
// ...
Write(4);
```

You can see the detailed list for all features [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Looks like you're missing 'static' and the link isn't helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do that in any way in current C#. `using` just puts the namespace into your code so you don't have to explicitly write it each time you need it.

If your class is `static` and you are using C# 6.0, you can do this:

```
using static System.Console;

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteLine("test");
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I was just a bit confused as I have been moving from VB (in which you can do this)

Comment: `using System.Console;` produces an error. Correct syntax is `using static System.Console;` as per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852389/how-do-i-use-the-c6-using-static-feature/31852390

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers has already explained this won't be possible until C# 6. You can however make your life easier with aliases that allow you to create an custom name for a type. It's very handy for example when some class has a longer name or for whatever other reason:

You define an alias by assigning a type to a name in the [using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). There are also few other things that you should know about it:

> - The scope of a using directive is limited to the file in which it appears.
> - Create a using alias to make it easier to qualify an identifier to a namespace or type. The right side of a using alias directive must always be a fully-qualified type regardless of the using directives that come before it.
> - Create a using directive to use the types in a namespace without having to specify the namespace. A using directive does not give you access to any namespaces that are nested in the namespace you specify.

```
using util = MyNameSpace.MyVeryLongNameStaticUtilityClass;
using other = MyNameSpace.MyVeryLongNameOtherClass;
```

Then you can use it like it was this type:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = util.ParseArgs(args);
    var other = new other();
}
```

Comment: Use these `using` directives to write something like `using ConditionalAttribute = System.Diagnostics.ConditionalAttribute` when you have to use the original name. It does only work for one specific class, you have to type the class name twice and you literally need to copy-paste-modify the line if you'd like to use multiple classes from a namespace.