# How do I use the C#6 "Using static" feature?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, static, using, c#-6.0

I'm having a look at a couple of the [new features in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) C# 6, specifically, 
*"using static"*.

> ***using static** is a new kind of using clause that lets you import static members of types directly into scope.*
>   <sub>(Bottom of the blog post)</sub>

The idea is as follows, according to a couple of tutorials I found,
Instead of:

```
using System;

class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Another message"); 
    } 
}
```

You can omit the repeated `Console` statement, using the new C# 6 feature of using static classes:

```
using System.Console;
//           ^ `.Console` added.
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        WriteLine("Hello world!"); 
        WriteLine("Another message"); 
    } // ^ `Console.` removed.
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to be working for me. I'm getting an error on the `using` statement, saying:

> *"A '`using namespace`' directive can only be applied to namespaces; '`Console`' is a type not a namespace. Consider a '`using static`' directive instead"*

I'm using visual studio 2015, and I have the build language version set to *"C# 6.0"*

What gives? Is the msdn blog's example incorrect? Why doesn't this work?

---

The blog post has now been updated to reflect the latest updates, but here's a screenshot in case the blog goes down:

> [image: blog]

Answer (score 244, accepted):

It appears the syntax has slightly changed since those blog posts were written. As the error message suggests, add `static` to your include statement:

```
using static System.Console;
//      ^
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        WriteLine("Hello world!"); 
        WriteLine("Another message"); 
    } 
}
```

Then, your code will compile.

---

Note that, in C# 6.0, this will only work for members declared as `static`.

For example, consider `System.Math`:

```
public static class Math {
    public const double PI = 3.1415926535897931;
    public static double Abs(double value);
    // <more stuff>
}
```

When `using static System.Math`, you can just use `Abs();`.
However, you'd still have to prefix `PI` because it isn't a static member: `Math.PI;`.

Starting with C# version 7.2, this shouldn't be the case, `const` values like `PI` can be used as well.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, but instead with `System.Math`, specifically `Math.PI`. When I use `using static System.Math`, methods like `Sqrt()` work but not a constant like `PI`. I have to continue writing `Math.PI` or the code doesn't compile. I'm curious as to why this doesn't work. Should I submit a new question for this?

Comment: @skwear: that sounds like material for a new question, yea.

Comment: As a quick answer to @skwear's question: _"using static is a new kind of using clause that lets you import __static__ members <...>"_. `PI` is not a _static_ member of the `Math` class. It's a constant. Simply put: the member has to be declared as `static`.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity for a new syntax like:
`using const System.Math;` :)

Comment: A better fix would be for the compiler to treat public constants as static. After all, they are used via the same syntax. :)

Comment: @DaveCousineau: I've updated the last line a little. Better?

Comment: @Cerbrus no, you fixed the part that I'm actually not 100% sure of. I said "const is static", but reading about it, I'm not sure that's correct to say. Regardless, you *can* import `PI` and other consts. I'm guessing this was a limitation of previous versions of C#, since this question is tagged as C# 6. With C# 7.2 I am able to use `PI` instead of `Math.PI`.

Comment: Ah, I'll look into this tomorrow, when I am on my DEV machine again.

Comment: The example in the Microsoft documentation claims PI can be used without prefix:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Comment: @GuneyOzsan: That wasn't the case when I wrote this answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for the detail. Looks like they later noticed the inconvenience and contradiction:)

Comment: One important point to consider with `using static` - it doesn't work for extension methods.

Comment: @MattArnold why would it? What use case would there be for `using static` with extension methods?

Comment: I had an extension method on a `Func<string, ICustomResponse>` but then later realized when I went to call it, it couldn't infer that a lambda of that type was of that type; so, to save changing the signature and potentially breaking other calling code, I wanted to call it like a normal static method but without the static class qualifier (e.g. `MyExtensionMethod(@string => new CustomResponse(@string))`).

Comment: Interesting that VB.Net uses `Imports System.Console`

Answer (score 4):

The `static` Keyword on a `using` statement will import only the one, specified type (and it's nested types). Furthermore you must not give the type name anymore. So just add static to your using.

Note: Please use this feature only when the two classes are logically closely related, otherwise it makes reading the code pretty hard.

Comment: _"you must not give the type name"_ What do you mean by that? Where did I do that?

Comment: Thobias, I'm not combining the two anywhere.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh the context of the 'as you did' accidentally changed, will fix that