# c# - VB 6 Code compare

Tags: c#, vb6

I want to write below VB 6 Code to C#

```
StartDate = '01/06/2015'
EndDate = DateAdd("d", -(Day(DateAdd("m", -(Month(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, StartDate)) - 1), DateAdd("yyyy", 1, StartDate)))), DateAdd("m", -(Month(DateAdd("yyyy", 1, StartDate)) - 1), DateAdd("yyyy", 1, StartDate)))
```

So i did this C# Code :-

```
DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1);
DateTime dtNo = StartDate.AddYears(1);
DateTime dt1 = StartDate.AddYears(1).AddMonths(-(dtNo.Month - 1));
DateTime dtDayNo = StartDate.AddYears(1).AddMonths(-(dtNo.Month - 1));
EndDate = dt1.AddDays(-dtDayNo.Day);
```

Just want to know is it correct? I am not getting the way how to test VB 6 Code.
So that i can compare the results of c# code with vb code.

Comment: If you have MS Office, VBA is a dialect of VB6.  If you put that into a macro, it should allow you to test the function of the VB6 version.  VBScript is also based on VB6, but I'm not entirely sure that the language supports everything.

Comment: If i were you, I would reference Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll and used `DateAdd` that is defined there (not for testing, for actual code).

Comment: @GSerg When using `Microsoft.VisualBasic` can i use the 1st code block in the above question & get the result of `EndDate` variable?

Comment: @Anup Yes, but you will have to put `DateAndTime.` before each function name because these are static functions in a VB module. Unless you're using C# 6.0 where you can [import static functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31852389/11683) with `using`.

Comment: You mean if i have to use `DateAdd` then i should use it like `DateTime.DateAdd`? I included the `Microsoft.VisulaBasic.dll` but I cannot find `DateAdd` method. Also i want to use `InStr`, I am not getting how to use this functions?

Comment: Put `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` at the top of the module, then use `DateTime.DateAdd` in code. Same for `InStr`, that's `Strings.InStr`.

Comment: I already included `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;`.I got `InStr` but not getting `DateTime.DateAdd`.

Comment: It's `DateAndTime.DateAdd`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question should be "How do I test VB6 code?"

Luckily, Microsoft has been lazy enough to never update VBA, which is the visual basic 6 variant that comes with microsoft office. Open MS Excel, click the top-left button, and click "options". There should be a checkbox saying something like "show developer tab in ribbon" (I have the dutch version so I don't know the exact text).

Once you've done that, close the options menu and go to the developer tab in the ribbon. Click "Visual Basic" and voila! You've got yourself a simple VB6 IDE that allows you to create forms and integrate them into your excel file.

Comment: `Microsoft has been lazy enough to never update VBA` - [not exactly true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3072356/11683). Also you can press Alt+F11 instead of all that.