# Not scoping static vars properly in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to C# - this is nearly my first program. I'm trying to create some public static variables and constants to use anywhere in the program. The - wrong - way I have tried is to declare them in a separate class in the same namespace but they are out of context for the main program. It's a WPF application. The code looks like this:

```
namespace testXyz
{
    class PublicVars
    {
        public const int BuffOneLength = 10000;
        public static int[] Buff1 = new int[BuffOneLength];

        public const int BuffTwoLength = 2500;
        public static int[] Buff2 = new int[BuffTwoLength];

        private void fillBuff1()
        {
            Buff1[0] = 8;
            Buff1[1] = 3;           
            //etc
        }

        private void fillBuff2()
        {
            Buff2[0] = 5;
            Buff2[1] = 7;           
            //etc
        }   
    }
}
```

Second file:

```
namespace testXyz
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static int isInContext = 0;
        int jjj = 0, mmm = 0;

        private void doSomething()
        {
            isInContext = 5;    // this compiles
            if (jjj < BuffOneLength)    // "the name 'BuffOneLength' does not exist in the current context"
            {
                mmm = Buff2[0]; // "the name 'Buff2' does not exist in the current context"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My actual program is much longer of course. I created the above WPF application exactly as shown to test this problem and I got these errors, also occurring in the real program. I really don't want to fill the arrays in the main program as they are very long and it would  mean much scrolling. I also want to have one place where I can declare certain public static variables. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't get why are you declaring the same namespace twice?

Comment: The 2 blocks are in 2 different .cs files in the project. Visual Studio generates the namespace declarations. I appended them in the example above.

Comment: Ok! Didn't read it any where so assumed that was in the same file.

Answer (score 8):

You have to either specify *class*:

```
// BuffOneLength from PublicVars class
if (jjj < PublicVars.BuffOneLength)  {
  ...
  // Buff2 from PublicVars class 
  mmm = PublicVars.Buff2[0];
```

or put [using static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852389/how-do-i-use-the-c6-using-static-feature):

```
// When class is not specified, try PublicVars class
using static testXyz.PublicVars;

namespace testXyz {
  public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    ...

    // BuffOneLength - class is not specified, PublicVars will be tried  
    if (jjj < BuffOneLength) {
      mmm = Buff2[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't access a static variable that is in another class by just calling the variable. You need to first go thru the class that contains it in your case it would be

```
PublicVars.BuffOneLength
```

and

```
PublicVars.Buff2[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. That answers it. I will prefix the vars with the class name. "Using static" would be a nice option, but I only have VS 2013...