# C# consoleApp Cannot call static method in separate class

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, constructor

I've been trying to make this function for the past few hours and hopefully master the use of classes. I have searched vigorously for answers but most of them do not seem to work in my case.

I created a class, `public class Car` as well as a constructor & method
 `static void ReadData()`

Now my goal here is to introduce a new instance of `Car` and call upon it so that console reads it out. The main problem is that under `public void main` it refuses to recognize my `ReadData()` method.

Here is my code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp13
{
class Program
{

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Car crossOver = new Car("BMW", "X4", 2015, "6/23/17");

        ReadData(crossOver);  // debugger says that ReadData does not exist 
       {
       Console.ReadLine();
       }
    }

}

public class Car
{
    private string make;
    private string model;
    private int year;
    private string whenSold;

    public Car(string mk, string mdl, int yr, string sld)
    {
        make = mk;
        model = mdl;
        year = yr;
        whenSold = sld;
    }
    static void ReadData(Car Car)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make: " + Car.make);
        Console.WriteLine("Model: " + Car.model);
        Console.WriteLine("Year: " + Car.year);
        Console.WriteLine("Sold at: " + Car.whenSold);
    }
   }
  }
```

I've tried several different ways of putting static before the scopes but it always ends in some error or the console application immediately exits out without reading the strings

Comment: Don't abbreative your parameter names. `mk, mdl, yr, sld` aren't clear. Follow normal C# conventions, use `make, model, year, whenSold`. And if `whenSold` represents a date, don't story it as a string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void ReadData(Car Car)
```

You didn't add an [access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).  The default is `private`.  That means you can't access it outside of the class.  You have to tell the compiler that other code can call this method.

```
public static void ReadData(Car Car)
```

Also, to *call* a static method that is defined on a Type, you must use the Type's name to call it.

```
Car.ReadData(someCar);
```

When you get the hang of that, you can actually get away without doing this by using a new feature of C# 6, [static usings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852389/how-do-i-use-the-c6-using-static-feature)

```
using static Car; // imports all static methods into the current context
{
    public void Main()
    {
        ReadData(new Car("lol"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not enough. The ReadData is in the Car class not in the Program class. It needs Car.ReadData.

Comment: @Steve ah, yeah. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I just tried this, and nothing changed. ReadData is still not recognized by public void main.

Comment: @S.Nog left out the other piece you needed.  Added.

Comment: Actually the default access modifier is internal not private. Not that it matters much in this case

Comment: @JesperNiedermann naw, that's for classes.  For methods, that's `private`.  It's always the most restricted for the given context.  So, I guess I'm calling myself a liar--nested classes without access modifiers are private...  But classes defined in a namespace without an access modifier are definitely internal.

Comment: Wow. You are right. I have been explicit about access modificers for so many years that I had forgotten that methods are not the same in this case. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Car in your code as well as the access modifier as @Will pointing out above. Should be

```
Car.ReadData(crossOver);
```

or with more changes what you could do is just *make it public* instead of static, *remove the Car parameter* adn then use `this.` instead of referencing the `Car` parameter and then call the code like this

```
Car crossOver = new Car("BMW", "X4", 2015, "6/23/17");
crossOver.ReadData();
```

Comment: +1, this is the best answer so far because it teaches the proper use of OOP - any time you are defining a static method inside a type that takes an argument of that same type, you should just make it an instance method instead. I'd even suggest changing the name from `ReadData` as that has nothing to do with the method's behavior - it's actually printing data out. `ReadData` would make more sense if it was a static factory method that returned a new `Car` that was already constructed based on a byte stream or other mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As the ReadData static function is part of the Car class, you have to make the function call as:

`Car.ReadData(crossover);`

The reason that the Main is not recognizing ReadData is because it is looking for its definition in the Program class.

Your entire code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Car crossOver = new Car("BMW", "X4", 2015, "6/23/17");
            Car.ReadData(crossOver);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        private string make;
        private string model;
        private int year;
        private string whenSold;

        public Car(string mk, string mdl, int yr, string sld)
        {
            make = mk;
            model = mdl;
            year = yr;
            whenSold = sld;
        }
        public static void ReadData(Car Car)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Make: " + Car.make);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + Car.model);
            Console.WriteLine("Year: " + Car.year);
            Console.WriteLine("Sold at: " + Car.whenSold);
        }
    }
}
```