# C# programming error - Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Tags: c#

Here is my code. I'm stuck with this recurring error and am at a loss for what to do next. Any guidance on what direction to look in would be great as I am learning how to code. The error message is listed below.

> **Error** CS0119: Expression denotes a 'type', where a 'variable', 'value' or 'method group' was expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace Kata
{
    public static class PascalsTriangle
    {
        new public static void Main()
        {
            int no_row, c = 1, blk, i, j;

            Console.Write("\n\n");
            Console.Write("Display the Pascal's triangle:\n");
            Console.Write("--------------------------------");
            Console.Write("\n\n");

            Console.Write("Input number of rows: ");
            no_row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (i = 0; i < no_row; i++)
            {
                for (blk = 1; blk <= no_row - i; blk++) ;

                Console.Write("  ");

                for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 0 || i == 0)
                        c = 1;
                    else
                        c = c * (i - j + 1) / j;

                    Console.Write("{0}   ", c);
                }

                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, on the line `for (blk = 1; blk <= no_row - i; blk++);` that `;` at the end will make sure that the next line is not part of the `for` statement, you'll need to remove that semicolon for the `Console.Write("  ");` to be apart of the `for` statement.

Comment: What line causes the error? That is usually really important info to include. Also, did you intend to write `using static System.Console;`?

Comment: Error is on that using static line.  But AlphaDelta has outlined another important issue with this code.  I would recommend using the { } curly brackets wherever possible.

Comment: @Rufus: do _not_ remove actual code when editing a question. The error very well could be (**and in this case is!**) related to the code you remove, and your edit to the question is such cases renders the question unanswerable, incomprehensible, or both.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks, I actually just noticed that I removed the namespaceand using part and was putting it back when I saw you already did - thanks!

Comment: @Rufus: well, I "put it back" only to the extent that I rolled back your edit. Feel free to edit again, this time not removing important parts of the code. :)

Answer (score 6):

Remove this line:

```
using static System.Console;
```

This line takes advantage of a syntax that isn't introduced until c#6 (see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852389/how-do-i-use-the-c6-using-static-feature)). You would only need to include that line if you wish to use `WriteLine` or `ReadLine` without specifying the class that it belongs to. Since you are not, you can take it out.

Or you could compile against c# 6 or Roslyn, where your code compiles fine-- see [this Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vcaciy).

I took the liberty of removing the extra `;` (see AlphaDelta's note) and I can get it to render a triangle. Output:

```
Display the Pascal's triangle:
--------------------------------

Input number of rows: 5
          1   
        1   1   
      1   2   1   
    1   3   3   1   
  1   4   6   4   1
```